# How to use native svn client for checkout in TeamCity

Tags: svn, teamcity, svn-checkout

I have a build agent located on machine with CentOS 4 (JDK 1.6). 
I faced a problem with checkout using svn client 1.7 - although it allows to track changes in repository, agent-side checkout is performing for a long time (up to 62hrs, even if i want to checkout 2Mb directory) till I kill the agent. Manual checkout on the machine works well. Moreover, the same steps in build configuration works on machine with higher versions of CentOS. But I can't change my OS due to several reasons.

Is it possible to checkout files in TeamCity using machine's svn client instead of svn client provided with a buildAgent?